# How to fade out mp4 audio AND video with FFmpeg?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, audio, mp4

How to fade out audio AND video in *.mp4 file?
If I try code from [this answer](https://video.stackexchange.com/a/19871):

```
ffmpeg -i "c:/input.mp4" -filter:v 'fade=in:0:30,fade=out:227:30' -c:v libx264 -crf 22 -preset veryfast -c:a copy "c:/testsong.mp4"
```

I get:

```
[AVFilterGraph @ 000001e0f41affc0] No such filter:  fade=in:0:30,fade=out:227:30'
Error opening filters!
```

Complete output:

> ffmpeg version N-86994-g92da230 Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers
>     built with gcc 7.1.0 (GCC)
>     configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-cuda --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-dxva2 --enable-libmfx --enable-nvenc --enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenh264 --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib
>     libavutil      55. 74.100 / 55. 74.100
>     libavcodec     57.102.100 / 57.102.100
>     libavformat    57. 76.100 / 57. 76.100
>     libavdevice    57.  7.100 / 57.  7.100
>     libavfilter     6. 99.100 /  6. 99.100
>     libswscale      4.  7.102 /  4.  7.102
>     libswresample   2.  8.100 /  2.  8.100
>     libpostproc    54.  6.100 / 54.  6.100
>   Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 's:/dummy.mp4':
>     Metadata:
>       major_brand     : mp42
>       minor_version   : 0
>       compatible_brands: isommp42
>       creation_time   : 2016-08-24T16:42:38.000000Z
>     Duration: 00:03:50.34, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 980 kb/s
>       Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 960x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], 851 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 50 tbc (default)
>       Metadata:
>         creation_time   : 2016-08-24T16:42:38.000000Z
>         handler_name    : ISO Media file produced by xyz...
>       Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 125 kb/s (default)
>       Metadata:
>         creation_time   : 2016-08-24T16:42:38.000000Z
>         handler_name    : ISO Media file produced by xyz...
>   Stream mapping:
>     Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> h264 (libx264))
>     Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (copy)
>   Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
>   [AVFilterGraph @ 0000000002d64580] No such filter: 'fade=in:0:30,fade=out:227:30'
>   Error reinitializing filters!
>   Failed to inject frame into filter network: Invalid argument
>   Error while processing the decoded data for stream #0:0
>   Conversion failed!

What' wrong here? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome! Please share the full console output, not just the one error.

Comment: Update your ffmpeg version to a recent one.

Answer (score 2):

## Fade both video & audio

First of all, the command you've provided won't achieve the desired effect: the **`fade` filter only applies to a video stream**, plus you specifically apply it to your input video stream with `-filter:v`.

To fade both audio and video, you'll need **both `afade` and `fade` filters**.

E.g.

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -filter:v "fade=in:0:30, fade=out:1770:30" -filter:a "afade=in:0:44100, afade=out:2601900:44100" -c:v libx264 -c:a aac output.mp4
```

This command fades in and out the first and last 30 video frames and 44100 audio samples, on a 1800 frames-long and 2646000 samples-long video (which, if your framerate is 30 fps and samplerate 44100 Hz, will be the first and last second of your 60 seconds-long clip).

Working with frames and samples can be highly impractical, so **to work with start and duration in seconds, use the `st` (start) and `d` (duration) parameters**, like so :

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -filter:v "fade=in:st=0:d=1, fade=out:st=59:d=1" -filter:a "afade=in:st=0:d=1, afade=out:st=59:d=1" -c:v libx264 -c:a aac output.mp4
```

(fades in and out first and last second of a 60s clip)

See [afade](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#afade) and [fade](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#fade) filters documentation for more details on parameters.

Alternatively, you can also use a **complex filtergraph** as suggested by Manul Hüttinger, which can be handy if you need to apply further filters to your clip:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -filter_complex \
  "fade=in:st=0:d=1, fade=out:st=59:d=1; \
   afade=in:st=0:d=1, afade=out:st=59:d=1" \
 -c:v libx264 -c:a aac output.mp4
```

---

## Regarding your particular error

I'm not sure where your error comes from, but you should try the following:

- First, **update your ffmpeg**: your libavfilter is in version 6.99.100, latest is at least 7.6.100
- I guess you're on Windows, given the filepath and build number. Beware that **you cannot use single quotes (`'`) on Windows, you must use double-quotes (`"`)**. Looking at the console output, this might be the origin of your error:

> `[AVFilterGraph @ 0000000002d64580] No such filter:
>   fade=in:0:30,fade=out:227:30'`

- Then, if it keeps failing, **try with a different input** (the error message might indicate an encoding/decoding error:

> `Failed to inject frame into filter network: Invalid argument Error
>   while processing the decoded data for stream #0:0 Conversion failed`

Answer (score 0):

try `-filter_complex "fade=t=in:st=0:d=30,fade=t=out:st=227:d=30"`

Comment: Can you explain the how this will work compared to what the OP already tried? That will make this useful to others trying to solve similar problems.